# Query in contraction of localization

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, localization

I was reading through Glaz's Commutative Coherent ring book, there I encountered a theorem where a part of it stated that

For two commutative rings with unity $S$ and $R$, where $S$ is a $R-$ algebra for a prime ideal $P \in Spec(S)$; $M_P$ is $R_P \cap_{R}$ flat, where $M$ is an $S$ module.

Now I am a bit confused in the notation, does the author want to imply that since $S$ is an $R$ algebra for every prime ideal $P\in Spec(S)$ if I take the contraction $p$ of $P$ in $R$ then $M_p$ is a flat $R_p$ module, or is it something else entirely.

Any insight or suggestion is most appreciated

Comment: It seems some additional hypotheses are necessary -- if $S$ is local and $R=S$, not every $S$-module is flat...

Comment: But in general, it seems your analysis of the notation is correct. The ideal $q=p \cap R$ is a prime ideal of $R$, and so $M_p$ is an $R_q$-module since $S_p$ is an $R_q$-algebra.

Comment: Yes $S$ is a finitely presented$R$ algebra, and thank you for the clarification.